# Facebook messenger can't process my .wav file

Tags: android, android-intent

I write the code like this. Also path is correct. But Facebook messenger can't hold my .wav file

```
String sharePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/test.wav";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/wav");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android

audio/wav is not a supported MIME TYPE. Check the above link for supported types